# How to list all the Chinese characters with `AR PL KaitiM GB` font in pdf file created by pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, cjk

List all the tested Chinese characters with  `AR PL KaitiM GB` in chrome.

vim test.html

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
p{
    font-family:AR PL Mingti2L Big5;
</style>
<p>
测试显示中文繁體漢字简体汉字
</p>
</html>
```

Then open it with chrome.

[image: all characters displayed successfully in browser with AR PL Mingti2L Big5]

Every character  displayed in chrome with `AR PL KaitiM GB` font.

```
fc-list|grep "bsmi"
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic-bsmi00lp/bsmi00lp.ttf: AR PL Mingti2L Big5,文鼎ＰＬ細上海宋:style=Regular
```

`bsmi` is the font of `AR PL Mingti2L Big5`.

Do the same task with pdflatex.

```
vim test.tex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}测试显示中文繁體漢字简体汉字\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

Change test.tex into test.pdf with `pdflatex  test.tex`.
Open test.pdf with pdf viewer.

[image: many Chinese characters can't be displayed i pdf]

Why so many Chinese characters can't be displayed such as `测试显简体汉` ?

To create my expected pdf file.

1.edit in libreoffice writer
open a new libreoffice writer ,input all Chinese characters with `AR PL Mingti2L Big5` font.

[image: edit in libreoffice writer]

2.clcik `export as pdf` in libreoffice menu
Open it with pdf viewer.
[image]

Here is my expected effect in pdf file which contain all Chinese characters with `AR PL Mingti2L Big5` font.
How to fix my test.tex file in order to display all Chinese characters with `AR PL Mingti2L Big5` font?

Another unsuccessful try.

```
vim test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AR PL Mingti2L Big5}
\begin{document}
测试显示中文繁體漢字简体汉字
\end{document}

xelatex  test.tex
evince test.pdf
```

[image]

```
lualatex  test.tex
evince test.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: I highly suspect that the `bsmi` font used by pdflatex is different from the one you saw in web browser or any fancy modern GUI thing. If I recall correctly, the former is divided into subfonts, each subfont contains no more than 256 chatacters in order to fit TeX's limitation. I would not be surprised if a Traditional Chinese font gives up simplified glyphs and vice versa.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use xelatex or lualatex then you can use the same font that is used by other applications on your system. pdftex can only use fonts with 256 characters which really isn't that good for Chinese so the cjk maintainers must have taken some version of the font and split it into multiple fonts, but these days using a version of tex that can use Unicode fonts is much simpler

Comment: You are assuming that libre office and the exported pdf uses `AR PL Mingti2L Big5` for some or all glyph only because the libre office dialog says so. But this doesn't need to be true. These applications can use fallbacks for missing glyphs. Check in the font dialog of the pdf which fonts are really included.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, I noticed that the glyphs displayed fine in my Emacs buffer, doing `M-x describe-char` I discovered Emacs was using `Heiti SC` font, so I tried

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Heiti SC}
\begin{document}
测试显示中文繁體漢字简体汉字
\end{document}
```

with `xelatex` and it works.

[image]

On the other hand, trying you first example using `pdflatex + CJKutf8`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{bsmi}测试显示中文繁體漢字简体汉字\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

I get 5 lines like this one:

```
Missing character: There is no K in font bsmiu6d!
```

and missing glyphs in PDF output like you report.

---

Surprisingly, trying the `fontspec` one with `lualatex` in place of `xelatex` I get a font not found error

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
./testchinese2.tex:3: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "HeitiSC" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

whereas `xelatex` found without problem this Mac OS X system-wide font.

---

Then I noticed that indeed `AR PL Mingti2L Big5` came with TeXLive (2018, pretest, I have partial intall, but containing CJK support) and I tried this

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{AR PL Mingti2L Big5}
\begin{document}
::测试显示中文繁體漢字简体汉字
\end{document}
```

Result with `lualatex`:

[image]

Result with `xelatex`:

[image]

I added the `::`  to better display that `xelatex` prints a blank in case of missing glyph. For some reason the glyphs seem missing from `AR PL Mingti2L Big5`. Here is log for `lualatex` run:

```
Missing character: There is no 测 (U+6D4B) in font ARPLMingti2LBig5:mode=node;+
tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 试 (U+8BD5) in font ARPLMingti2LBig5:mode=node;+
tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 显 (U+663E) in font ARPLMingti2LBig5:mode=node;+
tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 简 (U+7B80) in font ARPLMingti2LBig5:mode=node;+
tlig;!
Missing character: There is no 汉 (U+6C49) in font ARPLMingti2LBig5:mode=node;+
tlig;!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't trust applications like libreoffice (and browsers) in such things. They often exchange missing fonts or glyphs by something else.

I installed the `AR PL Mingti2L Big5` and tried to use it in libre office with your text:

[image]

But after the export to pdf the option dialog of the adobe reader doesn't report this font but two others:

[image]

and comparing at high zoom with a pdf created with lualatex one can see that the fonts differ:

[image]